# Informix parameterized odbc query doesn't work

Tags: c#, odbc, informix, parameterized-query

Parameterized query is not working as expected. When executing Informix ODBC command in c#:

```
OdbcCommand oc = Connection.CreateCommand();
oc.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, MAX(someattr) AS attr1 FROM ?";
oc.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter() { Value = table.Name, OdbcType = OdbcType.Char });
try
{
    OdbcDataReader or = oc.ExecuteReader(); //here the exception occurs
    ....
```

Exception occurs: ERROR [42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.

But the following code works without exception

```
OdbcCommand oc = Connection.CreateCommand();
oc.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, MAX(someattr) AS attr1 FROM {0}", table.Name);
try
{
    OdbcDataReader or = oc.ExecuteReader();
    ...
```

What might be the problem with parameterized query? :/

Comment: Parameters not work for table or column names

Comment: @Fabio Thank you. Additional question then. How to prevent SQL injection then if parameters are not supported for table or column names?

Comment: In duplicate question somewhere was very good suggestion: load all table names you going to use for your query from database and check if given table name is in loaded list.